# How do i fix the navigation bar and the drop-down content so it is in line and not overlapped?

Tags: html, css

How do i fix the navigation bar, so that the drop-down doesn't go over its parent and it's in line with it?
Also, how do i make the "About" tab to be filled when you hover over it? As you can see it only fills some of it, not until the end of the navigation bar.

There is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Shade1337/29sd0g07/

```css
.navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1078px;
}

.navigation a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 234px;
    height: 25px;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 214px;
        height: 25px;
    }

.navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    min-width: 214px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #4e3f3f;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Types
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Regular</a>
                        <a href="#">Cafe latte</a>
                        <a href="#">Espresso</a>
                        <a href="#">Cappuccino</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#shop">Shop</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>

            </div>
```

Comment: You want `bottom:0` at `.dropdown-content`. And you want `.dropdown .dropbtn {width:269.5px}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want. But here is the solution for what you asked. See the snippet answer.

```css
.navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1078px;
}

.navigation a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 234px;
    height: 25px;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;width:100%;
    }

.navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    top:71px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #4e3f3f;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navigation">
                <div style="width:25%;float:left">
                  <a href="#home">Home</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:25%;float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Types
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Regular</a>
                        <a href="#">Cafe latte</a>
                        <a href="#">Espresso</a>
                        <a href="#">Cappuccino</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:25%;float:left">
                  <a href="#magazin">Shop</a>
                </div>
                <div style="width:25%;float:left">
                 <a href="#despre">About</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: i removed height from .dropdown .dropbtn, added a width:inherit to .dropdown-content a and changed the width of the tabs. It looks good now but i have this tiny little space between the "Types" tab and the dropdown menu and it makes the dropdown disappear if i don't move quickly.

Comment: Yea, that is exactly what i want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote the answer and accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

> You will add bootstrap css file in your project and use bootstrap classes as per the your requirement

For more Info visit the link:-
    https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the first problem would be to add `height: 100%` instead of `height: 25px;` to `.dropbtn` class.

And the solution for the second problem would be to change the `width` of `.navigation a` and `.dropdown` and to change padding in `.navigation a` to `padding: 18px 0;`

Thus something as follows:

```css
.navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1078px;
}

.navigation a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: calc(1078px / 4);
    height: 25px;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(1078px / 4);
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 214px;
        height: 100%;
    }

.navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    min-width: 214px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #4e3f3f;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navigation">
   <a href="#home">Home</a>
   <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">Types
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Regular</a>
       <a href="#">Cafe latte</a>
       <a href="#">Espresso</a>
       <a href="#">Cappuccino</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <a href="#magazin">Shop</a>
   <a href="#despre">About</a>

</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/29sd0g07/2/)